# two of my Graphical Layout components are missing

Tags: android

I've recently started Eclipse and Android programming and I notices that alot of my Visual Components are missing their classes.

Such as the Sliding Tab (which I need for my UI) which only gives me this message when placed:

> error! ClassCastException:
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView
>   cannot be cast to
>   android.view.ViewGroup Exception
>   details are logged in Window > Show
>   View > Error LogThe following classes
>   could not be found:
>   - SlidingDrawer

And with the Tabhost & TabWidget:

> Error during post inflation process:
>   TabHost requires a TabWidget with id
>   "android:id/tabs". View found with id
>   'tabs' is
>   'com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView'
>   The following classes could not be
>   found:
>   - TabWidget

---

Answers would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you talking about the visual editor for views? It's probably a good idea to edit your xml files by hand.

Comment: Yes, the visual editor for views, but how exactly could I make a sliding tab when apparently the class is missing?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in the Layout Editor:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2021

I have the same issue, and only way you can do tabs, is to write it in xml.
Hope it gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as in the original Question, I think.
At least the problem with "TabHost" and "TabWidget".
Not even copy-paste out of this tutorial works!
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

But I now found a tutorial with sourcecode that actually works.
Don't know why though at the moment. 
Just try it.
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1/

There is another thing that I noticed. If I change the target plattform to Android 3.0 the graphical layout designer works without problems!

Answer (score 0):

There are ongoing improvements in the rendering libraries for the graphical editor.

See this issue for details:  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2021

Buried in there is a reference to the workarounds:

- Switch your platform for the graphical editor to a higher one, or
- Update to the latest ADT (r12 as of this writing) and install the preview rendering libraries.  This approach is detailed at the tools site: http://tools.android.com/download

The latter solution resolved the problems for me with the TabWidget.  Hopefully all will be integrated by r13 of the tools and the preview libraries won't be needed.